# string-append seems to identify a string as a list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, mit-scheme

I have the following code, which is supposed to return a list of the "list representation" of all possible trees with n nodes. 
Here's the code that I'm running using mit-scheme:

```
(define form1
  (lambda (elem)
    (cond
     ((null? elem) '())
     (else (string-append "(" elem ".)")))))

OB(define form2
  (lambda (elem)
    (cond
     ((null? elem) '())
     (else (string-append "(." elem ")")))))

(define tree
  (lambda (n)
    (cond
     ((= n 1) '("(.)"))
     (else (cons (map form1 (tree (- n 1))) (map form2 (tree (- n 1))))))))

(tree 4)
(tree 1)
```

And I get the following relevant output:

```
1 ]=> (tree 4)
;The object ("((.).)"), passed as an argument to string-append, is not a string.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

It seems to me that elem is a string, so why this error?

Comment: Your `null?` cases look odd for functions that are supposed to produce strings.

Comment: @molbdnilo I replaced '() with #f and I get the same error. I commented it out and still get the same error.

Comment: `#f` also looks strange if the functions are supposed to produce strings.

Comment: If you examine `(tree 1)` and `(tree 2)`, you will see that the former produces a list of strings while the second produces a list of lists of strings. This suggests that `cons` could be the problem.

Comment: ```""``` instead of ```#f``` produces the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says `("((.).)")` is not a string. It is correct. `("((.).)")` is a list of one string and `string-append` only works with strings and not lists.

`tree` takes a number and either returns a list of one string or it returns a tree (list of lists). Since the result of `tree` is passed to `map` and `form1` it's obvious that `form1` will get a list of one string as argument when `n` is 3 since `(tree 2) ; ==> (("((.).)") "(.(.))")` `(map form1 (tree 2))` will give an incompatible type `("((.).)")` which cannot be used in `string-append`.

I have no idea what this procedure is supposed to do, but the solution is to clean up the expected parameter types and their return value to be concise.